# Dynamically change button text in alert dialog

Tags: android

I've been messing with this for a few hours now, and just can't seem to find how to get it. Basically, I have an alert dialog for creating a password. There is a password field and a confirm password field. The listener checks if they match, and updates a textView. What I would like to do is change the text on the button from CANCEL to PROCEED when the two fields match. Everything is working up to that point...

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Add variables
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setpassword, null);
    final EditText password1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd1);
    final EditText password2 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd2);
    final TextView error = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PwdProblem);

    builder.setView(layout)
    .setTitle(R.string.hdrSetPassword)
    .setMessage(R.string.hdrSetPassword)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.hdrSetPassword, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
            String strPassword1 = password1.getText().toString();
            String strPassword2 = password2.getText().toString();
            if (strPassword1.equals(strPassword2)) {
                Register.password = password1.getText().toString();
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(CreatePasswordFragment.this);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else{
                // Set password to empty so it fails checks
                Register.password = "";
                mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(CreatePasswordFragment.this);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    password2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              String strPass1 = password1.getText().toString();
              String strPass2 = password2.getText().toString();
              if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {
                 // CHANGE BUTTON TEXT TO "PROCEED" HERE
                 error.setText(R.string.txtPasswordsMatch);
              } else {
                // CHANGE BUTTON TEXT TO "CANCEL" HERE
                 error.setText(R.string.txtPasswordsDontMatch);
              }
        }            
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
     });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

and in `afterTextChanged()`;

```
(AlertDialog)dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(yourString);
```

?

```
public class MenuFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String VALID = "OK";
    private static final String INVALID = "Not OK";

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        final EditText et1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        final EditText et2 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et2);

        builder.setView(layout)
        .setTitle(R.string.hello_world)
        .setMessage(R.string.hello_world)
        .setPositiveButton(INVALID, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                String strPassword1 = et1.getText().toString();
                String strPassword2 = et2.getText().toString();
                if (strPassword1.equals(strPassword2)) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  String strPass1 = et1.getText().toString();
                  String strPass2 = et2.getText().toString();
                  if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {

                      dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(VALID);

                  } else {

                      dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(INVALID);

                  }
            }            
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
         };


        et1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        et2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

        return dialog;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw something like that on another answer. But, no matter where I put the "Dialog dialog = builder.create();" I get an error on the second one, "getButton is undefined"/"AlertDialog can not be resolved to a variable"/non-final variable error...

If I tweak it to be
`final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`
and 
 `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("Test");`
it will run, but when triggered gives a NullPointerException error

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, it contains a fully working example now, based on your code.

Comment: Awesome man, thanks. I'm still not quite sure what I was screwing up. I think it was where I was defining the layout. But, when I just replaced the whole thing, works like a champ. Thanks again!

Comment: @NativeNerd You should call `dialog.show()` then change texts